# Interpretation of categorical variable coefficients in Linear Regression using sklearn's OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-encoding

I'm getting a little confused: when it comes to explaining the interpretation of coefficients of dummy variables in ML, all the sources say that one category is the reference level (i.e. 0) while the other categories are represented by binary variables. The coefficient of a dummy variable is the average difference in the label that we would have if the observed category is not the one of the reference level.

But it seems that OneHotEncoder encodes all the variables, without any reference level... If I have three categories, they would be coded as:

```
A B C
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

If the 3 coefficients are (say):

```
Coeff. A = 2.5
Coeff. B = 2.2
Coeff. C = 1.9
```

how can I interpret them in Linear Regression?